# why json serializer to model class error?

Tags: flutter, dart

#### json

```
{
"status":1,
"error":"error",
"data":{"id":10000,"email":"xxx@test.com"}
}
```

the data field is an arbitrary type of data

#### models.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class User {
  int id;
  String email;

  User({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.email,
  });
}

class Response<T> {
  final int status;
  final String error;
  final T data;

  const Response({
    this.status,
    this.error,
    this.data,
  });

  factory Response.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Response(
      status: json["status"] as int,
      error: json["error"] as String,
      data: (json["data"] as T),
    );
  }
}
```

#### user.dart

```dart
class User {
  int id;
  String email;

  User({
    this.id,
     this.email,
  });
}
```

#### code

```
Response resp = Response<User>.formJson(json);
print(resp.status);
print(resp.error);
print(resp.data);
```

#### exception

Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'User' in type cast

how to deal with it?
Does it need to be serialized again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json["data"]` is essentially a type of `Map<String, dynamic>`. There is no implicit cast to your `User` object so you have to explicitly cast that `Map` to a `User`. To do this you can do essentially the same thing you did with `Response`'s factory constructor.

Changes to `User` class:

```dart
class User {
  int id;
  String email;

  User({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.email,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json["id"],
      email: json["email"],
    );
  }
}
```

Changes to `Response.formJson`:

```dart
factory Response.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Response(
      status: json["status"] as int,
      error: json["error"] as String,
      data: User.fromJson(json["data"]), //or T.fromJson is that is a required capability and all your possible T's will have a fromJson constructor
    );
  }
```

Comment: But `data` is uncertain, there may be other objects;;;

Comment: @jack Look at my comment on the line of code with `User.fromJson(json["data"]),`. You can use the `T` generic, but you'll have to make sure every possible object has a `fromJson` constructor.

Comment: Is this better?? 
manual conversion
 ```
var resp = BaseResponse.formJson(json);
var user =  User.formJson(resp.data);
    
var resp = BaseResponse.formJson(json);
var article = Artice.FormJson(resp.data);
```

Comment: @jack as long as they are exactly the same it will be fine, including capitalization. Otherwise you could use `if` statements to check the type of your generic `T` and use a constructor according, but I think this method is cleaner.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your answer!!!

Finally choose manual conversion

Comment: @jack If it helped you and answered your question, please mark it as accepted and no problem!